# modification of variable elimination for underflow

Tags: probability, inference, algorithms, graphical-model, viterbi-algorithm

In Daphne Kollers book on Probabilistic graphical models exercise 9.3 asks the following

Ex 9.3 Consider a modified variable elimination algorithm that is allowed to multiply all of the entries in a single factor by some arbitrary constant. (For example, it may choose to renormalize a factor to sum to 1.) If we run this algorithm on the factors resulting from a Bayesian network with evidence, which types of queries can we still obtain the right answer to, and which not?

The reason i'm interested to a solution to this problem is for implementation. I'm interested in implementing the algorithm to prevent underflow issues. I can't seem to find a lot online about dealing with this especially for the sum product algorithm i've seen some stuff for max product. In particular this exercise is highlighted in chapter 10

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: How old is this book?  The overhead of taking logarithms and exponentials ceased to be a concern some 30 years ago.

Comment: It was published in 2009

Comment: Maybe, then, it's not the best resource for dealing with numerical issues.  There's a lot of good information out there, especially in numerical analysis textbooks.

Comment: cool, would you know the answer to the VE algorithm question specifically? What queries work if we scale factors?

Comment: I don't know the answer because the question only refers to a "modified variable elimination algorithm." It's unclear what precisely that might mean.

Comment: it says in the modified algorithm you can scale factors by multiplying them. I believe this would work if the factor isn't a factor with evidences but otherwise cannot be scaled. I'm trying to write code to investigate.

Comment: @whuber. [Variable elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_elimination) is a standard technique for efficient exact inference in [probabilistic graphical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model). The modification is stated in the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer is that you can answer queries of the form $P(A|B=b)$ but not of the form $P(A,B=b)$.

To see this, suppose that $F(A,B=b)$ is the outcome of the query. If we have multiplied factors $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ by scalers $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ then we get $$F(A,B=b) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^k c_i \right) P(A,B=b).$$ Then we can obtain the factor $$F'(B) = \sum_{B} F(A,B=b) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^k c_i \right) \sum_{B} P(A,B=b) = \prod_{i=1}^k c_i P(B=b).$$ Finally we get that $$\frac{F(A,B=b)}{F'(B=b)} = P(A|B=b)$$ as required.

To calculate $P(A,B=b)$ we would have to normalise at the end, which may not be part of the algorithm but is easy enough to implement.

Comment: I am not following your reasoning in here, you can normally reduce the factor to given evidence and continue with the inference ?